# Can Octave's rand function produce an output where all (or some) numbers are equal?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, octave

In the [documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/rand.html) for the `rand` function, it is said that:

> Return a matrix with random elements uniformly distributed on the interval (0, 1).

My question is: is there *any* chance that any of these random numbers (or all) are equal in the output?

---

As a side note, I am curious about this because it is suggested in Andrew Ng's Machine Learning Course to use the `rand` function when randomizing the values (hence breaking symmetry) of all thetas, when training a neural network.

Comment: don't know who down-voted this question, but tis a perfectly reasonable question for someone new to ML and Neural Networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, if it was truly random, then yes - there is always a small chance that all the values will be equal. However, these are floats - so there are lots of tiny little differences. If your worried about getting exactly the same values for a few weights, you should buy a lot of lotto tickets - your much more likely to win one!

Even if a few weights ended up being *exactly* identical, and then unable to change - that wouldn't inhibit the network as a whole all too much.

Modern regularization techniques, such as drop-out, make the (not really an )issue even less so. Dropout will only use a random subset of the neurons for each training batch, and only those ones get updated - so if two weights were tied, eventually one would be selected for a batch (and its weight adjusted) and the other left alone - thus breaking the symmetry.

Note: the rand function isn't truly random, its *Pseudo* random. The documentation says it uses the Mersenne Twister PRNG, which is a relatively high quality (not crypto good) well known and trusted PRNG. If you had a very low quality PRNG, getting exact duplicates could be a potential issue - but you should be safe in this instance.